# is there a way to style xe:basicLeafNode? Need to make source image rectangular

Tags: css, xpages

It seems to be easy to make an image rectangular on your xPage:

```
<img class="img-circle" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/brad-pitt_416x416.jpg">
```

but not for basicLeafNode. Here is the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:navbar id="navbarTop" pageWidth="fixed" fixed="fixed-top" inverted="false">
        <xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
            <xe:basicLeafNode imageHeight="50" imageWidth="50"
                style="cursor:default;"
                image="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/brad-pitt_416x416.jpg">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
    </xe:navbar>
</xp:view>
```

Eventually it will be an user icon/image. So I want to make it rectangular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assign `class="img-circle"` to your basicLeafNode image.

You would do this by adding a `styleClass` property

```xml
        <xe:basicLeafNode imageHeight="50" imageWidth="50"
            style="cursor:default;"
            styleClass="img-circle"
            image="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/brad-pitt_416x416.jpg">
        </xe:basicLeafNode>
```

Unfortunately, the class "img-circle" gets assigned to surrounding `a` tag only and has no effect on image:

[image]

To fix this, add the following client side JavaScript code to your XPage. It adds `class="img-circle"` to the image tag too:

```xml
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            dojo.query(".img-circle").forEach(function(node){
                node.childNodes[0].className = "img-circle";
            });
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

[image]

The complete XPage looks like this then:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:navbar id="navbar1" pageWidth="fixed" fixed="fixed-top" inverted="false">
        <xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
            <xe:basicLeafNode imageHeight="50" imageWidth="50"
                style="cursor:default;"
                styleClass="img-circle"
                image="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/brad-pitt_416x416.jpg">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
    </xe:navbar>
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            dojo.query(".img-circle").forEach(function(node){
                node.childNodes[0].className = "img-circle";
            });
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you, Knut.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the `style` property to render the leaf node. However you might want to look at the "other end" and cut the uploaded image to size before you store it. In HTML changing the image size doesn't alter the image and it's load time. It also might distort the image rendering.
Another approach would be to use `background-image` in the style which does show just a part of the image based on the container size